# How do you merge two Git repositories when one is a subdirectory of the other without losing commit history?

Tags: git, merge, commit, subdirectory, repo

### Current folder structure

- /root: server code exists here
- /root/client: client code exists here (a subdirectory within the server's directory).

### Current git tracking

- 1 repo tracking Server code in /root that gitignores the entire client directory
- 1 repo tracking Client code only within /root/client.

### The Problem

I am trying to merge these two repos *while keeping one as the **subdirectory** of the other*, combining the historical commits of both (not losing any).

### Findings So Far

I have found a lot of situations resolved on the Internet in which two repos have either 1) the same files or 2) will eventually be merged together at the same folder level, but have not found much on merging two repos if one is a subdirectory within another.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: I think this is done with merge with subtree strategy. https://git-scm.com/book/en/v1/Git-Tools-Subtree-Merging

Comment: This worked for me! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This steps will merge both `master` branches:

1. Move the client project folder to a folder to outside the server folder (for example, `tmp_client`)
2. Inside the new client project folder (`tmp_client`) create a new folder called `client`.
3. Move all the content from the `tmp_client` to the new `client` folder
4. Add and commit the changes:

   `git add -A .` to add the changes

   `git commit -m "Move content to client folder"`
5. Add a new remote branch for the server:

   `git remote add server git_server_repo_url`
6. Pull changes from the server master branch

   `git pull server master` This will merge the changes
7. Push changes to the server git repository

   `git push server master`

PD: If you want to be sure all is ok in the server branch, you can create a new branch instead of pushing it to the working bramch of the server and then merge the new branch.

Comment: Thank you for your answer; seems like it might work. I took Edmundo's suggestion and that resolved the problem for me in my case.