# merge sub folder git repo into root folder repo retaining commit history to create a single repo

Tags: git, gitlab, opencart2.x

I have searched and tried multiple solutions from past 2 days and nothing seems to be working out for me.

I currently have the following directory structure which is opencart framework

```
[git repo 1]
  -admin
  -image
  -CB [git repo 2]
    -catalog 
  -system
  -vqmod
```

I need to merge repo 2 into repo 1 and move the `catalog` folder back into the original flat folder structure and track it as single repo, with all the history from repo 2 and merging also because I need to setup `git-flow` on azure in coming days.

So the final structure should be in single repo:

```
[git repo1]
  -admin
  -image
  -catalog
  -system
  -vqmod
```

In the initial phase i made a mistake of thinking there was no need to include other folders except for `catalog`, but now there is a  requirement to work with entire opencart framework modules.

### SOLUTIONS TRIED:

[solution 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44658948/how-do-you-merge-two-git-repositories-when-one-is-a-subdirectory-of-the-other-wi) => as suggested in comments here, subtree is not the solution i am looking for because i want to remove repo 2 from the scene and manage only 1 repo (repo 1).

[solution 2](https://bneijt.nl/blog/post/merge-a-subdirectory-of-another-repository-with-git/)

[solution 3](https://www.vlent.nl/weblog/2013/11/02/merge-a-separate-git-repository-into-an-existing-one/) => closest solution that i could find, but it did not work as it still keeps the files inside subdirectory `CB/`

There may be similar questions but nothing that worked out, if there are some answers i have missed please point me to the right direction.

Help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: More reading: [blog](https://saintgimp.org/2013/01/22/merging-two-git-repositories-into-one-repository-without-losing-file-history/) /

[another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1425892/how-do-you-merge-two-git-repositories)

Comment: I believe with the provided solutions of merging two repos to one, you just need one extra commit to do the folder layout. You have to have a project folder (root of .git, like `CB`), but you can use one extra commit to smooth the folder structure. Let me know if this is possible.

Comment: @C.Arendt thanks , let me try.

Comment: @chenrui i did not really understand the part of "one extra commit" , an extra commit is fine for me but what and how that commit should be?

Comment: I presume something like `git mv ./CB/* ./`.  A commit that moves your files into the current directory.  I don't think removing the directory should be necessary at that point, but may be something you need with `git rm`

Comment: @C.Arendt yes, you just need git mv the folder, and then the folder layout will meet your needs.

Comment: @Zammer I tried the solution 3, actually, there is just one merge commit (merge remote branch commit) from repo2 to repo1, is that what you really want?

Comment: @C.Arendt the first you suggested "blog" worked for me with some cut down and tweaks, same as said by chenrui

Comment: @chenrui yes, you were right thats exactly what i came up with after looking at the link given by C.Arendt . Thank you